# Both '.' and ',' for decimal separator in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: windows, libreoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I have read [How to set decimal separator in Libre Office Calc?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250677/how-to-set-decimal-separator-in-libre-office-calc) but I haven't found an option for this:

**Is it possible to set both `.` and `,` as decimal separator in LibreOffice Calc?**

In France it's `,` but as I use both French and other-regions documents, it would be helpful to have both accepted by LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the language (and thus, the decimal separator) even *per cell* (or per document, see below). Thus, if your language is set to French, with `,` as decimal separator, you can still use `.` as decimal separator (and accept documents respectively) if they have a proper language setting.

You can check this yourself: just modify the cell's language setting by using the cell formatting features (context menu or Menu `Format` -> `Cells...`). Thus, you can even *mix different decimal separators in the same document*.

Here's a small example:

[image]

My localisation is set to German, so the comma is the default decimal separator. A2 and C2 contain both the value `2.5`. A2 was formatted with en-us language settings (has to be done before entering the value!), thus the value is recognized as number, and the sum in A3 is calculated correctly. C2 has no special language format, thus no number recognition, wring sum.

### EDIT:

To set the language for a whole document, the easiest way is to modify the default cell style. To do so, open Menu `View` -> `Styles` or hit <kbd>F11</kbd>. Right-click on `Default`, select `Modify`, and select the `Numbers` tab. There you can set the default cell language setting.

After modifying the default cell style, you may have to restore the numeric values, e.g. by doing a regex-based search and replace (search for `^.*$`, replace with `&` - see https://superuser.com/a/394170/84724 )

Comment: Very interesting! How to set the language for the whole document? (And not per cell; because if LibreOffice has to store lang metadata for 100'000 cells this is duplicated data)

Comment: @Basj: I've amended my answer to cover that point, too.

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu. Fun fact: let's say the language is initially French for a .xlsx file. Let's say the numbers are like this: `123.45`, and then you perform this (`F11 > right click on Default > Modify > Number > English`) then ... the cell `123.45` is transformed to `'123.45` i.e. text, arghh! So the only solution is to do a Search&Replace `.` by `,`, and do the language change *after*...  But if you have two operations to do in this process (Search&Replace + Lang. change), then the lang. change is not really so useful...

Comment: @Basj: i can't test it myself, but you could try to apply the dirty hack described here: https://superuser.com/a/394170/84724 to get rid of the single quote. If this works in your case, too, you could proceed by (1) adapting the default cell style and (2) transform the "text number values" to number values again... But you still have two operations, so no really nice solution. Would be nice to know how excel handles this use case...